# Is the sequence $(1 + (-1)^n)$ Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis

We're supposed to prove or disprove the statement that $(1 + (-1)^n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. I don't think it is because this function oscillates and doesn't converge, so I don't think it's Cauchy. Why or why not is this a Cauchy sequence? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Cauchy $\iff$ convergent, for sequences of real numbers

Comment: How could I show that this sequence is not convergent?

Comment: It has two subsequences that converge to different values (actually they are constant). Try with terms with odd and even indices.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $\left \vert a_{n+1} - a_n \right \vert = 2$ for all $n$. So is this sequence Cauchy?

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the definition of *Cauchy sequence* directly. Note that if $a_n=1+(-1)^n$, then

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
2,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
0,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $\epsilon>0$. If the sequence is Cauchy, there must be an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_k-a_\ell|<\epsilon$ whenever $k,\ell\ge m$. Now consider $|a_k-a_{k+1}|$ for any $k\in\Bbb N$; it’s equal to ... ?

Answer (score 3):

If the series converges to a limit $L$, then for sufficiently big values of $n$, you'd have $(1+(-1))^n$ between $L\pm1/10$.  Thus two consecutive terms would differ from each other by less than $2/10$.  But $0$ and $2$ do not differ by less than $2/10$.  Hence the sequence diverges.  Therefore it's not a Cauchy sequence.

**PS:** There are some who say that although some sequences are Cauchy sequences, no sequence is Cauchy, since Cauchy is a man who lived in the 19th century.  The idea is that the term "Cauchy sequence" is a compound noun, rather than "Cauchy" being an adjective.  I sympathize with this view, but mathematicians generally don't even suspect there is such a view.  Language is messy.

Comment: I suppose the height of reputation comes when your surname becomes an adjective, like Freudian or Kafkaesque.

Comment: "Freudian" and "Kafkaeque" are adjectives because of their suffixes; "Freud" and "Kafka" are not.

Comment: "no sequence is Cauchy, **since** Cauchy is a man who lived in the 19th century." That's a strange argument: there was and is more than one person named "Cauchy".  "Cauchy sequence" is a mathematical term: it gets a formal definition.  The standard one of course is "A sequence is **Cauchy** if..." According to this definition, "Cauchy" is clearly an adjective.

Comment: You don't have to like the terminology or even use it: an internet search shows that a few people speak of "Cauchian sequences", so you could try that.  But there is absolutely nothing illicit about the standard use of the term: a word is an adjective if it is defined and used that way, period.  This usage is not unique to mathematics: e.g. people say "Allen wrench" and no one says "hand me an Allen", so "Allen" is an adjective here.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : A good definition would say is "A Cauchy sequence is....".  Yes, it is being used as an adjective if you insist on saying "a sequence is Cauchy".  But read my whole comment.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark : And read your own comment too!  You said "'Cauchy sequence' is a mathematical term".  You didn't say "Cauchy" is a mathematical term.  Of course "Cauchy" is a mathematical term when used by those who write "This sequence is Cauchy."  But writing "A Cauchy sequence is...." does not commit one to that usage, since one could treat the term "Cauchy sequence" the way one treats the term "landing strip".  No one says "This strip is landing", but sometimes they say "This is a landing strip."

Comment: "A good definition would say is "A Cauchy sequence is...."." I'm not sure what "insist" would mean: I absolutely use "Cauchy" as an adjective, as do many others.  Do we have to?  No, but we want to.  And we want an adjective, because we're describing a *property* of something.  We describe sequences as convergent or divergent; it would be very weird not to have a grammatical equivalent for this other fundamental property.

Comment: ....in other words, in compound nouns like "landing strip", the word "landing" is not a adjective.  One could say "This hair stylist's implement is a hair curler" but one would not say "This curler is hair", thus distinguishing it from something that curls something other than hair.  "Hair curler" is a compound noun; "hair" is not being used in it as an adjective.

Comment: I offer you an escape from Hell and you're not interested.

Comment: @Michael: By the magic of English grammar, my definition of "Cauchy" as an adjective gives rise to the correct definition of "Cauchy sequence".  Could you define *only* "Cauchy sequence" and regard it as a compound noun?  Of course.  But we don't want to: we want an adjective for this important *property* of a sequence.  Don't use it if you want, but we can and we will.